# How to mark a question on SO as resolved?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

I hate to ask another question just so I can close one. But I don't seem to see how to mark one of my questions as resolved. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the green checkbox on the left if the answer is acceptable. If you just want to delete the question, the delete link is to the bottom left of your question. If you answered your own question, you can't mark that as the answer for 3 days, but not to worry because it won't count against your accept rate.

Answer (score 0):

Go to my questions, pick one of them and try to mark answers in your questions just as I did with that 'green mark' ;)

Comment: Bro, I went to my profile and saw the 4 questions I've asked (including this one), clicked on one of them and don't see any green mark at all..

Comment: I see it now. Thanks, Dude. I didn't see a 'green mark.' But then I saw the up and down arrow with a clear 'check' mark and realized what you were saying. I accidentally chose Chris' answer and when I went to fix it and choose you instead I realized his answer was more complete and clear. Thanks a lot, though, man.